# Scapy - Script VS Command Line IPv6 Call

Tags: scapy

Trying to make a simple sr1 call to get an IPv6 address.

If I insert the command directly in scapy:

```
i = sr1(IPv6(dst="www.google.com")/ICMPv6EchoRequest())
print i.src
```

I'll have no error.
However, if I write that in a python script and then launch it, I get the error:

> ERROR: [Errno -9] Address family for hostname not supported

I tried doing the same thing with IPv4 and it works just fine. How come?